# Django sets csrftoken twice

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django app and I am currently trying to set my production server.
However, every time I try to access the admin page, it goes in a redirect loop (meaning the page keeps sending me back to login).

```
10.0.0.2 - - [25/Aug/2015:17:36:01 +0300] "POST /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 
10.0.0.2 - - [25/Aug/2015:17:36:01 +0300] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 
10.0.0.2 - - [25/Aug/2015:17:36:01 +0300] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 879
```

I have done some searching, and I suspect that the cause is the fact that I have different csrf tokens for the request and the response (see attached image).

I don't really know why this is happening, and everything works fine in the development environment. I also tried this in several browsers, deleted the cache, did a reset on my database ... none of these worked.

I am using django 1.8 with nginx and uwsgi.

[image]

Comment: No, this is definetly not a reason. `csrftoken` will be generated when session is created, what we can see in above situation. 

What isn't normal is that you don't have any session before logging in. So I'm suspecting that your sessionid cookie is disappearing just after you're logging in.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could this be because I have set SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE to True ?

Comment: What is your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally figured out what was wrong. In my `settings.py` file I had the following settings:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

and this was preventing the browser from setting a correct sessionid/csrftoken.

For these to work, you need a couple of other things, such as CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN and SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN. I also had those, BUT you also need your server to ensure a **secure (https)** connection...

Given that I only need this for a school project, https was not mandatory, so I just removed the first two settings, and now everything runs smoothly.

Thanks to everyone that tried to help me.